# How VMware components work each other

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I am beginner in VMware. I am trying to understand the VMware components and how it works.But I could not understand how vsphere Client access the EXSi host. Is it directly or through the VMWare VCenter server.please give any reference or explanation to get the understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vSphere client you can connect to vCenter or directly to host. Of course if host is added to vCenter you should to connect ONLY to vCenter because vCenter should to know about any changes made on hosts. Connecting directly to host should be done ony in emergency situations (e.g. vCenter is down).

Answer (score 0):

V-Center is the umbrella, under which all EXSI can be controlled. We can assume an example of a company where we have 3 physical servers installed ESXi on it and each server has as many processors cores so it can handle 5 virtual machines on it.

**Now What is EXSi** ---- EXSI is the product/OS/kernel which will allow you to create the environment to run multiple Servers/OS on the same hardware.

**V-sphere client/V-sphere Web client** --- If you have only one EXSI Server and you want to control that server functionality you need v-sphere because taking direct connection of EXSI Hardware machine will not allow you to do much with it. so the v-sphere client will give you many tools to play with it.

**V-Center/VC** ----- Now what if when your company has many ESXi servers as we taken for example. V-Sphere can not control all of those into one centralized platform. Here VC comes into play. VC allow you to manage all of these servers under one tool and many other functionalities which are not available in V-Sphere like Distribution switch, V-Motion(Which allow you to migrate one VM machine from Hardware to hardware in the fluctuation of time or not human noticeable time ).